# Mysql Database query error in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x

My database cannot query. when i run this code then it's show me an error .

```
def button_click(self):
    # shost is a QString object
    shost = self.le.text()
    if shost:

       s_h = "127.0.0.1"
       s_n = "root"
       s_p = ""
       s_d = "code"

       s_cn = mdb.connect(s_h, s_n, s_p, s_d)

       cursor = s_cn.cursor()
       today = datetime.date.today()
       mac = get_mac()
       query = "INSERT INTO `ac` (`acc`, `mac`, `date`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
       re = cursor.execute(query,(shost,mac,today,))          

       if re: 
           self.ex = Example()
           self.ex.show()

       else:
          query1 = "SELECT * FROM  `ac` WHERE  `acc` = %s,`mac` = $s"
          ck = cursor.execute(query1,(shost,mac))
          if(ck):
             self.ex = Example()
             self.ex.show()
          else:
              print 'no'
```

I want to know how to write sql code with python variable so how can i fix it ?

```
  query = "INSERT INTO `ac` (`acc`, `mac`, `date`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
   re = cursor.execute(query,(shost,mac,today,))
```

and

```
          query1 = "SELECT * FROM  `ac` WHERE  `acc` = %s,`mac` = $s"
          ck = cursor.execute(query1,(shost,mac))
```

Answer (score 2):

> `query1 = "SELECT * FROM`ac`WHERE`acc`= %s,`mac`= $s"`

`$s` - this is not a valid placeholder, replace it with `%s`.

Comment: Nothing happen it's still error and $s is printing mistake

Comment: @alibaba What errors are you getting? You may also need to commit after the insert: `mdb.commit()`.

Comment: This Error :    


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tanver\Desktop\pypro\final.py", line 51, in button_click
    re = cursor.execute(query,(shost,mac,today,))          
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'Sabbir' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Comment: @alibaba and this is a different problem. You have a unique key constraint and you are violating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
re = cursor.execute(query % (m, n, k))
```

Comment: you should add some explanation for better post quality